# How to use data from a database with a MS Bot

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am going to do my next project on ChatBot for my client. I am a .net person, so planning to use MS Bot with C#.

My question is on creating the Database part. We have a existing Database which has data related to Project Management and others which is currently being used for a web application.

What we are expecting from the Bot is, if a person(say, a manager of particular project)wants to know the count of people under him, he can use the Bot to get the count, rather than go to the web application and figure out.

How will this database work for Bot application.
How will I create the table structure to identify the questions to be asked to BOT and its responses and fetch data and then display to user.
How can we make my Bot fetch data from this DB, if someone asks question.
How can I store these responses.

I am totally confused. My Client do not want to use LUIS, but want similar thing to be built with our Database and can be called via RestAPI.

Kindly help with any article or advise to start my work with.

Comment: This is a general advice question that’s better suited to discussion forums like [Quora](http://quora.com), or Reddit’s [`/r/programming`](http://reddit.com/r/programming/). Stack Overflow is specifically about programming-related questions as they pertain to actual code. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com).

Comment: A bot built using the Microsoft Bot Builder is just a website.  You can use a database the same way you would in any other website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the bot you made as a back-end server written in C#.
It just gets requests and sends responses.
So nothing special is needed for connecting it to DB.
Simply connect it to DB as you'd connect a ASP.NET website to DB.